# Is composite primary key a cql 3 only feature ? And can cql 2 access data inserted with cql 3?

Tags: cassandra, cql

If I use CQL 2, the keyspaces appear, but i can't use because it says it does not exist. And i need to know if i can make compound primary keys with cql 2.
Thanks

Comment: I've just found about the difference in case sensitivity in the keyspace naming between cql 2 and 3. I'm using java hector,  I would like just an example of how should I code to retrieve a row with composite primary key.

Comment: The one Im working is (Year int, Month int, DayofMonth int, UniqueCarrier varchar, FlightNum int) as primary key. Oh if you happen to know how to paginate throught that too, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean **composite** primary key?

From [Datastax documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/dml/using_cql):

> CQL Specification 3 supports composite columns. By virtue of the
>   composite primary keys feature in CQL, wide rows are supported with
>   full denormalization.
>
> CQL Specification 2 supports dynamic columns, but not composite
>   columns.

Sadly the composite columns (and composite PKs) are only available in CQL3, but most of the latest APIs support CQL3.

Comment: Thanks, its because I never saw anything affirmative that Hector was compatible with cql 3.